# Setting expiry time for a collection-property in mongoose (mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I know, if i want to set the expire time for one collection with the `expires` property like so:

```
new Schema({
  token: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    expires: '10s',
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

But, how can i set the expire time for one **property** in a collection?

For example i have an schema with username, email and a array of authentification tokens. I want every token to be deleted from the creation date after 10s. I tried:

```
new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tokens: [{
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      expires: '10s',
      default: Date.now
    },
    auth: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }]
});
```

But every time the complete collection will be deleted, not the token object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate collection for holding authentication tokens, and maintain a one-to-many relationship between user and token collections.

you can cascade `insert/update/delete` using `pre/post` middlewares, so when token expires de-reference token in user

user schema

```
 const UserSchema =  new Schema({
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },    
    tokens: [
       { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Token' }
      ]    
  });
```

token schema (make sure you have created `ttl` index on `createdAt`)

```
  const TokenSchma = new Schema({
      user : { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' 
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        expires: '10s',
        default: Date.now
      },
      auth: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      token: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: Yeah, but the remove-middleware to de-reference the token from the user don't work. When the time expires the middleware wont fired (There is already an issue on the github site from mongoose).

Comment: in that case we can remove token reference from users, just have a ref to user in tokens